# custom private message block generates error

Tags: blocks, privatemsg

I created a block to generate a private message link to send a message to all the users of a group. I use the php code as the text format on the block body.

```
<?php
$group = og_context();
$og_id = $group->gid;

$query = db_select("og_membership", "ogm");
$query->condition("ogm.gid", $og_id, "=");
$query->fields("ogm", array("entity_type", "etid"));
$result = $query->execute();

$result_tmp = $result->fetchAll();
$recipients = array();

foreach($result_tmp AS $tmem)
{
$recipients[] =  user_load($tmem->etid);
}

echo '<a href=/';
echo privatemsg_get_link($recipients,$account = array(),$subject = NULL);
echo '>Send message to ehood members</a>';
?>
```

When I use this, It created me a notice message saying -

> ```
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in privatemsg_user_access() (line 335 of /sites/all/modules/privatemsg/privatemsg.module).
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in privatemsg_user_access() (line 335 of /sites/all/modules/privatemsg/privatemsg.module).
> ```

Although it generated the link, It creates the error. I think its somehow related to how $account is mentioned ?

i tried to send global $user instead of $account, but still creates the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the problem is that [privatemsg_get_link()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!privatemsg!privatemsg.module/function/privatemsg_get_link/7) uses `array()` as default value for `$account`, but then uses the following code.

```
  if ($account == NULL) {
    global $user;
    $account = $user;
  }
```

The function should use `NULL` as default value for `$account`, in the same way [user_access()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/user_access/7) does.

```
function user_access($string, $account = NULL) {
  global $user;

  if (!isset($account)) {
    $account = $user;
  }

  // ...
}
```

The error message you see is because the function tries to access `$account->uid` when `$account` is an empty array. An array doesn't have properties, and that is what the message is saying.
As the function is passing that value to `user_access()`, the same error would be raised from `user_access()`, which check the value of `$account->uid`, and for which an empty array is not the correct value to pass to its `$account` parameter, which requires an user object, or `NULL`.

It's fine to use the default values a function has, but you should check what the function does when it gets the default values for its parameters.

It is wrong to call a function as `privatemsg_get_link($recipients, $account = array(), $subject = NULL)` when you want to use the default values for its parameters. Just call the function as `privatemsg_get_link($recipients)`. With your code, you are setting `$account` to an empty array, and passing `$account` as parameter.
PHP doesn't have [named parameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_parameter), but only positional parameters. If it had named parameters, it would be possible to call a function indifferently as `functioname(34, param3 = 4, param2 = 12)`, or `functioname(34, param2 = 12, param3 = 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

`privatemsg_get_link($recipients,$account = array(),$subject = NULL);` is not the proper way to call a function. You should be passing in values for $account and $subject, not using what the function defines as default values. Consider this:

```
<?php
$group = og_context();
$og_id = $group->gid;

... more code ...

global $user
privatemsg_get_link($recipients, $user, 'Some subject line');
?>
```

When a function defines default values, like

```
function my_cool_function($array = array()) {
  // If the array passed to the function is empty, or if an array WASN'T passed...
  if ($array == NULL ) {
    // Create one.
    $array = array('some cool stuff');
  }
}
```

you shouldn't pass in the same default values, but rather real ones.

Also, I would verify that user_load() returned a valid user object before passing it along. What if it returned FALSE as it couldn't load a user? Something like:

```
if ($account = user_load($row->etid)) {
  $recipients[] = $account;
}
```

**Protip!** You don't have to run `->fetchAll()` on a db_select object if you've just run `->execute()` – you could just do

```
$result = db_select('table', 't')->fields('t', array('id'))->execute();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  print $row->id;
}
```

The fetchAll() method, among other fetch methods, is very useful if you're passing data around or using it in other ways, but if you're just iterating in a foreach() loop you don't need it.

Post back here if none of this solves the issue and I'll revise my answer. Also, do the community a favor and revise your question title to be more of a question, including the "pivatemsg" module (or whatever it's called) since this questions is explicitly regarding that module.